# How to get all User (Object) related fields from Active Directory - both on premised and cloud based (Azure)

Tags: java, python, azure, active-directory

I wanted to know how to get all User (Object) related fields from Active Directory - both on premise and cloud based (Azure).

Is it possible to attach dynamic fields/columns with various objects in AD , particularly User object? If yes, can we get the list of all fields that are applicable for a particular object type?
Just like SQL, can we do something like "select * from users", so that we can get all the fields as well as their values?

I am OK with any implementation - python, ruby, java

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, you can implement your needs via two steps as below.

1. Integrating your on-premises identity system with Azure AD, please see the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) to know how to do.
2. Performing CRUD operations using Azure AD Graph API (not like SQL), that you can try to use any languages via programming in [SDKs](https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=graph) or [Graph API REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx).

There is a [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-java-graphapi-web/) for calling the Azure AD Graph API in a Java web application which you can refer to.